# Why am I getting my disk partition full without adding anything on it?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My "C" disk partition has a total of 34 gbs of space and if i select all the folders and files shown in there, with the hidden files and folders too, it tells me that those folders are using just 24 gbs of space.The problem is that the windows tell me that i have under 1 gb of free space in "C".

Using Windows 8 x64 OS with 4GB's of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good tool called WinDirStat (http://windirstat.info) that helps you to analyse where your free space is gone.

This is much more detailed than what Windows provides in the folder properties.

Try to scan your C: partition with this tool and see if you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more complex informations about your files, folders on your partitions, try something like this one http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/index.html

But the best for you will be resizing of your WIN 8 partition, example
http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-8/low-disk-space-windows-8.html

What about this one? It worked for me.
After that, I would recommend you resie your "C:" partition ;)

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2527-windows-old-folder-delete-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Well then i'll just resize the disk space and this will be it.Thanks for your answers <3.

Comment: Please try to make your answers more substantial. Simply posting links is not helpful. Try to replicate the answer here, in case the linked website ever goes down.

Answer (score -1):

The space on your hard disk is not all taken up by user data files.

Just to begin, the system cannot index single *bytes* - it groups them in chunks called *clusters*. For performance reasons a cluster should be aligned to disk sector boundary (it was easier when said sectors were 512 bytes, before WD and large-size sectors), and a multiple of the disk sector length. Some prefer an integer power of two of the sector length, so 2 sectors, 4, 8, 16, or even 32.

Let's say that your NTFS system has *clusters* of 4Kbytes. This means that no file can occupy *less* than one cluster, and therefore a 1K file occupies 4Kb of disk. You can see this by asking for file properties: it will give you the file size, and the *file size on disk*, which is usually larger. There are techniques to avoid small files to suck up an inordinate quantity of disk space, but as a rule, *for each file on the disk you lose half a cluster*. So if you have 500,000 files and 8K clusters, that's two gigabytes lost just then and there.

Then, the system has to *keep track* of files - their owners, their permissions, their metadata, any alternate data streams, the lot. All this also takes space in the so-called [Master File Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are techniques - *lengthy* techniques - to shrink and compact the MFT on a disk, better than what is done by Windows File Defragmenter, which *may* recover several gigabytes.

Finally, it could have happened that you did *not* actually select *all* your files, but left out some hidden and system files, many of them useless. The problem lies in sifting the dross: I once deleted a "useless" MSI file, and Microsoft Office stopped working.

A disk area that often gets overlooked is the System Recovery. The System Volume Information directory, if selected, could tell you "zero files and zero directories" -- but that's *not true*. If you [gain access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309531/en), you will see it holds lots of files. You might have a couple dozen recovery points for the last month; but if your system had no troubles in that period, you can usually safely delete all but, say, the last week.

A nifty utility that can get you many gigabytes and usually no troubles at all (unless you've got a *really* really dirtied-up system) is Piriform's [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). It also has a "registry cleaner" function that is sometimes really useful, and a selective Recovery Deletion that's much better than the bundled utility.

Comment: This doesn't even address the auhthor's question.  The author claims he is only using `24GB` of a `34GB` partition yet Windows claims he only has 1GB free.  Of course you might have guessed what the problem is, the System Recovery, that more then likely is whats using his space.

Comment: I beg to disagree. This exactly, even if long-windedly, answers the author's question: "Why do nine gigabytes seem to have disappeared?". The short answer would be, *Windows and NTFS do this routinely*. Actually, all OSes and FSs do. Then I *also* listed some of the *ways* in which this happens :-)